# What are the extended homogeneous coordinates in the EdDSA specification?

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, eddsa

According to the [EdDSA specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032#page-17) from the IETF:

> For point addition, the following method is recommended.  A point (x,y) is represented in extended homogeneous coordinates (X, Y, Z, T), with x = X/Z, y = Y/Z, x * y = T/Z

I'm unfamilar with extended homogeneous coordinates, and I'm used to seeing points as simply (x, y).   Can anyone explain where the T and Z variables come from in the specification document?

**UPDATE:**

I found [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389324/how-to-calculate-point-addition-using-jacobian-coordinate-system-over-elliptic-c) that has some great detail:

Comment: Did you see the articles on the page 48?

Comment: I did have a look through that section, and especially the "EdwardsPoint" class on page 50, but I couldn't see what the T and Z variables are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extended homogeneous coordinates are a different form of coordinates that provide particularly fast methods of point addition and point doubling formulas for twisted Edwards curves, introduced in [Huseyin Hisil, Kenneth Koon-Ho Wong, Gary Carter, Ed Dawson. Twisted Edwards Curves Revisited, 2008](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/522).

$X$ and $Y$ roughly correspond to affine $x$ and $y$, $Z$ comes from [regular extended (also called projective) coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) as a scaling and $T$ is the actually “new” element that contains $X\cdot Y$. In particular, section 3 of the paper by Hisil *et al.* introduces the extended homogeneous coordinates and how to convert to and from extended homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: That's helpful - thanks xorhash!

Comment: in reading section 3 of that paper, is states that: "an  auxiliary  coordinate t=xy to represent a point (x,y) on a x2+y2=1+dx2y2 in extended affine coordinates (x,y,t). One  can  pass  to  the  projective  representation  using  the  map  (x,y,t)→(x:y:t:1)".  So does that mean that Z is always 1, and T is always x * y ?

Comment: @simbro When going from *affine* to *extended homogeneous*, $Z$ is always $1$ and $T$ is always $x\cdot y$, yes. The inverse operation from extended homogeneous $(X:Y:Z:T)$ to affine $(x,y)$ is $x=X\cdot Z$, $y=Y\cdot Z$ and ignore $T$ entirely.

Comment: Much appreciated. Like everything else, it's obvious once you get it :-)

Comment: @simbro Correction, but I can't edit the comment anymore: $x=X\cdot Z^{-1}$ and $y=Y\cdot Z^{-1}$, note that we take the multiplicative inverse of $Z$.

Comment: sorry to keep asking questions, but the modular multiplicative inverse is the same as division, sort of, so wouldn't ⋅−1 be the same as X / 1?  i.e. x divided by 1?

Comment: @simbro Yes, $X\cdot Z^{-1} = \frac{X}{Z}$. The thing is that *all* of the the coordinates $(X:Y:Z:T)$ change when doing the [fast Edwards point addition formulae by Hisil et al.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/522). So $X\cdot Z^{-1}$ will usually have $Z\neq1$.